# Windows Form Application Size

Tags: c#

I was doing some Design today and I realised that when I was debugging my application, the size I was precising in the properties of the form wasn't really saving but it was giving me a size a bit bigger than what I wanted (as show in the picture). I tried many things but nothing worked, and of course, I'm talking about the properties not adding for example : this.size = new size(..,..) because I don't really want to do that for the moment. 
If anyone can help it would be really nice.
Here's my problem in a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVwy2.png

Comment: What is the border style of your form? Witzh a fixed size border you can simply design your form in the visual designer.

Comment: Hi Sefe, thanks for replying early. My Form size is "371, 465". Let me know if you would like to see the code.

Comment: You could also try set the maximum size so that it doesn't grow beyond what you see in the designer if you want it to be resizable but within a reasonable range.

Comment: Fabulous, I tried this method but still, it did not work. Thank you tho.

Comment: And if you set a fixed size border as @Sefe suggests, how does it behave?

Comment: I have a solution to the white space problem if you're willing to have the form resizable. I would have thought a max size or the fixed size border would have addressed that.

Comment: What do you mean with fixed size border? is it something I can find in the properties?

Comment: As long as my codes won't be affected, then yes.

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial comment, check out the `FormBorderStyle` property.

Comment: I tried doing the FormBorderStyle like you mentionned Sefe but I did not work..

Comment: Could you please paste or send your code to review.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to upload files here, so here's a link to my code. I just uploaded it on Media Fire: http://www.mediafire.com/file/amu7zm7xzn4mbi0/WindowsFormsApp1.rar/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I have identified the source of your problem after downloading the code you pasted (and as a result completely changed my answer). I'd recommend editing the question and putting the link there so it can be easier to find. It seems you created some resources at some point, and one of them was overriding the size in your designer. Remove the `ClientSize` and `MaximumSize` resources and the property overriding will stop and you will get the behavior you expect.

[image: Resources defining new sizes.]

To get to this, expand the Login.cs form and see the `Login.en.resx` file which defines the offending new sizes.

[image: The resource file with the new sizes.]

You should check the other resource file because I saw another client size defined in there.

Comment: I also tried this method Fabulous, but it is also not working. Might it be a bug that Visual Studio has?

Comment: By doesn't work, do you mean the controls are not resizing and moving to fill up the remaining space?

Comment: @HusseinKhamis I have updated my answer after finding the problem. Have a look now

Comment: Heyyy Finally haha, I left the project waiting for an answer and yours worked, thanks alot man!

Answer (score 0):

If you are designing and finding the design different from what you did in design,
then look at the Form properties, you will find a property named :

> AutoScaleMode

and you'll find the value :

> Font

just like this photo :

[image]

What it did really : it resizes the components and the form itself based on pc Font, scale and size. Like this picture : ( **From Display Settings in Windows** )

[image]

So if you change the pc scale and font size settings : you'll find that your app resizing itself and you'll find everything is different from what you designed before.
So All you have to do is changing the `AutoScaleMode` property in your form to **`None`**

[image]

which will guarantee that the Form and components size will stay as it is even if the pc settings changed. So your design will stay as it is on different pc's and settings.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I tried doing what you sent but I did not help me, sadly. The size was working yesterday but suddenly, it stopped giving me the size I am putting in the properties.

Comment: So weird. I fell in this problem before and this worked for me, since the form is taking the real size and font from pc settings, by settings the property to None, it'll size itself based on ur design !

Comment: It is probably a bug.. can you check my application? I left a media fire link.

Comment: Well, there is something wrong with your app. Even If I change the sizeMode to resizable, nothing changed. But the other Form ( Home ) acts normally. So I would suggest to recreate that form (Login) cuz really I don't know what happened there.

Comment: Yea as expected.. thank you tho!